# Displaying weather in notification center

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I was wondering how can i display the weather of a particular city of my choosing in the Notification center? I'm using an iPhone 5S with iOS 7.1

Right now it only shows the weather using the Location service. When i turn off the location service for the weather app, it doesnt show any weather at all in the notification center, although i have added the city in the weather app?

Comment: so this did not work for you http://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Default-City-for-the-Weather-Application-on-iPhone

Comment: @Buscar웃 nope, tried it earlier. It doesnt show anything regarding weather in the notification center using this method =(